# Insert a WHERE conditional in Table creation code for AWS Athena

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-athena, presto, trino

I need to create a table with a specific condition that can be updated when the bucket is updated. This is an example:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `default`.`cards-test` (
  `id` bigint,
  `created_at` timestamp,
  `type` string,
  `account_id` bigint,
  `last_4_digits` string,
  `is_active` boolean,
  `status` string,
  )
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe'
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetInputFormat' OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetOutputFormat'
LOCATION 's3://something/cards-bucket/'
TBLPROPERTIES ('classification' = 'parquet');
```

Now, let's say I want a WHERE clause that says `WHERE type = 'type_1'`, can I insert this here? If so, where?

If not, how should I create a table with such specific conditions out of the buckets?

Answer (score 1):

No, as [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/create-table.html) show the syntax for `CREATE TABLE` - there is no option to provide filtering the data.

What you can do - create another table via [`CREATE TABLE AS`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/create-table-as.html) syntax with filtering applied:

```sql
CREATE TABLE cards-test-type_1 WITH (
  ...
) AS 
SELECT 
  * 
FROM 
  cards-test
WHERE type = 'type_1'
```

Or create a [view](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/create-view.html):

> Creates a new view from a specified SELECT query. The view is a logical table that can be referenced by future queries. Views do not contain any data and do not write data. Instead, the query specified by the view runs each time you reference the view by another query.

```sql
CREATE VIEW cards-test-type_1 AS
SELECT 
  * 
FROM 
  cards-test
WHERE type = 'type_1'
```

Comment: Understood, thank you. But, I tried a similar approach before, and unfortunately this table doesn't get updated when the Bucket 's3://something/cards-bucket/' gets updated. Is that doable?

Comment: @AquilesPáez as written in the [Using CTAS and INSERT INTO for ETL and data analysis](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/ctas-insert-into-etl.html) doc - _"When new data becomes available, you can use an INSERT INTO statement to transform and load the data into the table that you created with the CTAS statement."_ - it seems there is no build in option to autoupdate the CTAS table.